# White screen while rendering game

Tags: java

When I run my game the JFrame is just white. Can someone explain?
I have no idea why this is happening and I'm having a really hard time finding out what could be the issue. I hope one of you can explain/know the answer. I look forward to hearing your answer and I would love to continue coding but I'm stuck atm, - Artycal.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

static GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];

private static JFrame frame;

private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)width, (int)height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
private BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;

private static double width = screenSize.getWidth();
private static double height = screenSize.getHeight();

private boolean running;
private Thread thread;

private BufferedImage player;

public void  init() {
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    try{
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/sprite_sheet.png");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
    player = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32);
}

public void run() {
    init();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if (delta >= 1){
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println(updates + " Ticks, Fps " + frames);
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void render() {

    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(new Color(81, 218, 221));
    g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(new Color(81, 218, 221));
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

    g.setColor(new Color(255, 174, 80));
    g.drawImage(player, 100, 100, this);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

}

private void tick() {

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();

    frame = new JFrame("Game");

    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension((int)width, (int)height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int)width, (int)height));
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)width, (int)height));

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

    //device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);

    game.start();
}

private synchronized void start() {
    if (running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private synchronized void stop() {
    if (!running)
        return;

    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/sprite_sheet.png");  means you look for a file at the root of your disk (not at the root of the project). You sure it is what you have?

Comment: Yes, It's in my resource folder and it has worked on my other games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some things to note:

1. INT_ARGB for BufferedImage has a default alpha of 0 (completely clear) so unless you change the alpha value of the pixels you wont see anything.
2. drawRect draws only the outline of the rectangle. use fillRect to draw the entire rectangle.
3. as far as I know, drawing BufferedImages does not use the current color of the Graphics object as they are mainly defined as a rectangle made of different colored pixels. try drawing to the Images own Graphics object if you want to change its color.
4. you are exactly overlapping two drawings (the image and the rect) so you will only ever see one.

I hope I have finally been of some help.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make things clear, here are the things I did:
1. I made INT_ARGB to INT_RGB
2. I made it fillrect
These 2 things seem to fix it.